# Issue with nested flex layout using angular-material shorthand

Tags: css, angularjs, layout, flexbox, angular-material

I'm having a hard time telling what's wrong with the following layout.

I'm trying to keep a SPA layout with the "deepest" component only being scrollable if the VH is too small (marked in the snippet with `overflow-y:scroll` and `border: 3px solid black`), the parent divs should follow the viewport boundaries anyway.

http://codepen.io/minikrob/pen/yJKzKj
Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/r27nL.png

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this ?

Edit: It was an issue with an older version of Google Chrome... thanks again to @kuhnroyal & @Chanthu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inner container with the black border is the one you wanted to scroll, have a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wxzkmr

The fix was to add `height:100%;` to elements `.pusher` and `#content-wrapper`.

How does that fix it? hmm... css is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular-material `layout="column|row` on the parents and `md-content` for the scrollable element.

```
<div flex="" class="maincontent pushable" layout="column">
  <div flex="" class="pusher" layout="column">
    <!-- ngView: content-wrapper -->
    <md-content id="content-wrapper" flex="">
```

Here is a working pen: http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/QEmOvk

And you should read https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container

Comment: Thanks **kuhnroyal** and **Chanthu** for answering, the thing is I need : 
 
- the green border div to be flex-shrank into the orange border one   

- the black border one to be contained inside the green one, margins 
included

Here is an example of what I'm trying to acheive : 
http://i.imgur.com/zq0tbx5.png

Comment: From what I can tell, this is exactly as the pen behaves.

Comment: Ok, thanks for insisting, the problem seems to come from Chrome as you pen effectively works on FF... Now to find the root issue... Thanks again !

Comment: It works the same in FF and Chrome for me. What version of Chrome are you using? I am on 53.

Comment: Thanks again, it was indeed an issue with my version of Chrome (formerly 48) !!